# Is there any way to make changes to the icon overlay registry work without restarting explorer?

Tags: c++14, msdn, explorer, shell-extensions, shell-icons

I am looking for a way to make changes to the icon-overlay work without restarting pc or restarting the explorer.
It would be very kind, if anyone can offer some help or idea.